# How to remove ImageButton's standard background image?

Tags: android, imagebutton

In `ImageButton` I want to remove the standard button background image. In http://developer.android.com it is said, that one must define his\her own background image or set the background color to be transparent. I tried to set a black background, but it didn't make any effect...

Answer (score 225, accepted):

You can use `android:background="@null"` for your [ImageButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html).

See also:
    [Android Developers official guide on Buttons](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html)

Answer (score 43):

The best choice is not set a transparent background to your `ImageButton`.

Give to your user a feedback when the button is tapped.

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

Comment: Superb Solution. this answer should be marked as right.

Answer (score 25):

`ImageButton.setBackgroundResource(0)`

Comment: Excellent!  This is the solution for programmatically doing Mudassir's solution.  Thank you!

Comment: It's setBackgroundResource, not setBackgroundResources.
Use it like this : ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.my_button)).setBackgroundResource(0);

Answer (score 8):

use the following property in your in the xml of ImageButton:

```
android:background="@drawable/icon"
```

where icon is the name of the image kept in your drawable.

Comment: This is a cleaner solution than setting the `src` and nulling out the background.

Answer (score 5):

No, it has to be transparent, not black. Try color: #00FFFFFF

Answer (score 2):

Dot't use `button.setBackgroundResource(0)`;
on some devices you will get:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

Better use `button.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
android:background="@null"
```

in your layout xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
YourImageButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myButton.setBackgroundResource(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Kotlin, you can do this:

```
val myImageButton = ImageButton(context).apply({
    background = null

    // and if you need to add drawable, simply use:

    setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, 
                         R.drawable.ic_save_black_24px))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest android version, the background image doesn't remove even when you set `android:background="@null"`.

Setting `android:minHeight="0dp"` works for me.