# How can I assign the default background to a Button?

Tags: android, android-widget, background-image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove ImageButton's standard background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457138/how-to-remove-imagebuttons-standard-background-image)

I've set a custom background to a `Button`. Now I want to revert this change and display the default background of the `Button` again. How can I do this?

Comment: Copied your question title into google, the first hit is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457138/how-to-remove-imagebuttons-standard-background-image). -1 for no research effort.

Comment: @alextsc I want to remove background of Button(and want to set default background) not of image-button .and if I try to set null or transparent image in background of Button then Button becomes disappears.why??????

Comment: r u setting background to imageButton somewhere??

Comment: @AtulBhardwaj The code is the same for both the ImageButton and the Button widget *(which you would have know if you tried before asking)*. Also you should reword your question, I misunderstood it *(along other people apparently)*. I was under the impression that you wanted to remove any background, including the default one, not that you wanted to reset a custom background to default.

Comment: @AkashG first of all It's not a image button,it is a button.What I do is that I am fist changing background of button then trying to make buttons background as it was by default.

Comment: that is what i was asking u.pls post what u hv done??

Comment: @AkashG  first I did this btn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.checked)) ;  .Now i want to remove this background and want to get Button's default background.how???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is simply to remember which Drawable you had as the background before you set it to a custom one, e.g. save it in `onCreate()`.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
    defaultButtonBackgroundDrawable = button.getBackground();

    // set a custom background here, or somewhere else. 
    // Just make sure that the default one is saved before you modify it.
}
```

where `defaultButtonBackgroundDrawable` is a member variable of your activity and `button` keeps a reference to your button. This way you can restore the default background pretty easily by doing

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(defaultButtonBackgroundDrawable);
```

Comment: thanks for this solution.It works fine for me  But I found one other solution  that also works  btn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_default));

Answer (score 2):

You can use `android:background="@null"` for your `Button`.
or `button.setBackgroundResource(0);`
or `button.setBackgroundDrawable(null);`

Comment: button.setBackgroundResources(0); This is giving error as this method is undefined for button.  and button.setBackgroundDrawable(null); makes my button disappear.

Answer (score 2):

By programatically, you can do something like,

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
button.setBackgroundResource(0);
```

Comment: My button becomes disappear by setting button.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got solution of my problem  `btn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_default));`
This makes my button's background as it has by default.