# Android Delete setBackgroundResource image

Tags: android

How to delete the image of `BackgroundResource` from button?
For example: `b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.breakdown)`
I'm sure that `setBackgroundResource(0)` is not available!
Thank you

Comment: `I'm sure that setBackgroundResource(0) is not available!` why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove ImageButton's standard background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457138/how-to-remove-imagebuttons-standard-background-image)

Answer (score 0):

**try this  using this you will get   default button style.**

```
btn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_default));
```

or this

```
b.setBackgroundResource(null);
```

or this

```
b.setBackgroundResource(0);
```

Comment: @游智博 did you try this `btn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_default));`

Comment: yes, it would reset the all button's property and style, but I just want to stop showing image

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
b.setBackground(null);
```

The documentation states:

> Set the background to a given Drawable, or remove the background.

Also:

```
b.setBackgroundResource(0);
```

The documentation states:

> Set the background to a given resource. The resource should refer to a
>   Drawable object or 0 to remove the background.

**Edit:**
Because you stated that it does not work, I wrote this to test it, and it works perfectly:

```
final Button btnTest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_test);
btnTest.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.some_drawable);
Button btnClean = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_clean);
btnClean.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
          btnTest.setBackground(null);
     }
});
```

Comment: That cannot be. I updated my answer, I just wrote a small piece of code to test it and it works perfectly.

Comment: Also, as someone else said, you can use setBackgroundResource(0); this exists and is usable, from doc: "Set the background to a given resource. The resource should refer to a Drawable object or 0 to remove the background."

Comment: Still no reaction

Comment: It is as same as yours

Comment: No, please, post the code that you have, you cannot say that is the same when mine is working. What is your context? where do you have the button? is it on a list? recyclerview? in a basic layout?. Please post the xml and the code as an edit in the original question. Otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code...

```
b.setBackgroundResource(null);
```